# What does 要不不留学要留学就要留出个性 mean?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

In the following sentence:

> 俗话说的好，**要不不留学要留学就要留出个性**。。。。。。这是我编的。。
>    我们来看看我们社会主义坚实伙伴的古巴。古巴是西班牙语国家，抽雪茄，晒太阳都是家常便饭。

The whole sentence would be something like:

> ... This is what I wrote. We see Cuba, our socialism's solid mate. Cuba is a country where Spanish is spoken, and a cigarette and sunlight are all in everyday meal.

However, I don't understand the start of the sentence. Specifically,

- How should it be divided grammatically?
- Why does it use 不 consecutively?
- What is the meaning of the whole sentence?

Answer (score 1):

要不 / 不留学 / 要留学就要留出个性

"otherwise / don't study abroad / if you study abroad you should do it with personality"

or more idiomatically:

"if you're going to study abroad you should do it with personality, or not at all"

Note that 要...就要... is a common grammar pattern.

Answer (score 0):

They are saying, if you want to study abroad, go to Cuba, it's a cool place. (I agree! Viva Cuba! Vive la revolución!)

俗话说的好，
There is a good saying

要不(要么)不留学,
either don't study abroad

要留学就要留(学）出个性
or study abroad with flair

这是我编的
(Actually) I just made this (saying) up

我们来看看我们社会主义坚实伙伴的古巴。
We came to see our loyal socialist comrades from Cuba.

古巴是西班牙语国家，
Cuba is a Spanish-speaking country,

抽雪茄，
smoke cigars,

晒太阳都是家常便饭。
bask in the sunshine, those are everyday things (in Cuba)